# Verticle lines on external screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, microsoft-surface, docking-station

I bought a new samsung odyssey G5 ultra wide screen (3440 x 1440) for my surface book 2, I use HDMI (high speed cable from Xbox One X) -> HDMI to USB-C adapter -> surface dock 2 -> surface book2. This connection works fine with my SONY 4K TV.

When I first connected the screen to my surface dock 2, everything seemed fine, but after adjusting screen resolution, many evenly spread vertical lines appeared, I did a screen test and I am sure that the screen itself is fine. I have installed samsung's official driver and updated my display card driver, but nothing changed.

What could be the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. MS states, " if your cable is over 3 feet it can be a problem." 2. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/troubleshoot-connecting-surface-to-a-second-screen-bc8f5121-a4cb-cf0b-5770-2df7a66a3b28 3. Try using the display at a different resolution; it might be the Surface 2 doesn't work well at that resoluton.

Comment: I tried everything but nothing worked. I then unplugged the monitor, clicked on return on amazon and then went to sleep. This morning I decided to give it a last try, I plugged it, opened my laptop, and the monitor worked just fine. I then restarted my laptop, and again, the problem appeared. I am confused.